# Javascript sticky menu - mistake on console

Tags: javascript, sticky

Hi I have a problem with Sticky-menu. I'm trying to get it work. On the console I have information: 
1. Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
    at HTMLDocument.
2. Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at myFunction (app.js:86)
    at window.onscroll (app.js:77)
What is wrong with this code?

HTML code:

```
<header class="nav_main">
            <div class="about_nav">
                <p><a href="#b1">Lilando</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="price_nav">
                <p><a href="#b2">Cennik</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="lilando_nav">

            </div>
            <div class="gallery_nav">
                <p><a href="#b3">Gallery</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="contact_nav">
                <p><a href="#b4">Kontakt</a></p>
            </div>
        </header>
```

CSS code

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
    }
.nav_main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;}
```

java Script code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navMain = document.querySelector("nav_main");
    var sticky = navMain.offsetTop;

    function myFunction(){
        if(window.pageYOffset >= sticky){
            navMain.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navMain.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for `querySelector(".nav_main")`.

Comment: The error says what the problem is ("**Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of _null_..**") - trust it and work backwards. eg. *why* is x null in `x.offsetTop`? That is, the "question" here after initial debugging should be "Why is document.querySelector(..) returning null?", and that itself can be easily explored in the console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm ok with Obsidian Age ;)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navMain = document.querySelector(".nav_main");
    var sticky = navMain.offsetTop;

    function myFunction(){
        if(window.pageYOffset >= sticky){
            navMain.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navMain.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
```

```css
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.nav_main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav_main">
    <div class="about_nav">
        <p><a href="#b1">Lilando</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="price_nav">
        <p><a href="#b2">Cennik</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="lilando_nav">

    </div>
    <div class="gallery_nav">
        <p><a href="#b3">Gallery</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact_nav">
        <p><a href="#b4">Kontakt</a></p>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Oooooo! Thanks! Whats a stupid mistake :/ Thank you for yours answers.